# MarketingCloud SDK - Xamarin Android- Couldn't access subtitle field

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I'm currently working with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK in my Xamarin project. In the SDK response, I notice that the subtitle field is missing, even though I've set it in the SFMC dashboard.

Comment: Subtitle isn't missing. It's not supported on Android.

Comment: @BillMote What about iOS?

Comment: Google does not support subtitle, that's not a Salesforce limitation. Apple does support subtitle, and you should find it available in our objects/notifications, but only if it is sent from the MC server.